# Auto construct child classes from parent class PHP

Tags: php, oop

I don't know if this is possible so i will try to explain as best as I can.

I'd like to have a parent class that is easily extensible by "plugin" child classes that may or may not be present.

```
class Foo {
__construct(){
   $this->foo = "this is foo";
}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   function construct(){
    parent :: __construct;
  }
   $this->foo = "foo is now bar";
}
```

but I don't want to have to initialize class Bar with $bar = new Bar every time i need it, b/c from class Foo I won't know what child classes are available.. and ideally i'd like it to scale so it doesn't matter.  i'd like the child class to automatically initialize any time there is a call for a new Foo.

is this possible... is there a better way to go about it so that I can use the child class to modify a variable in every instance of the parent class??  i'm working within WordPress, so I think I could give class Foo an action hook that any child classes could hook into, but I am wondering if there is a natural PHP way to achieve this.

Comment: Got to be honest, not sure what you're asking. You don't want to initialise `Bar`, but you want `Foo` to initialise any and all child classes that extend it? What are you trying to achieve here?

My impression is you just want to be able to have child classes extend a Base class, and manipulate the Base classes' values such that code run from the Base classes' constructor inherits values from the child. Though that's not quite the way you've described it, is that what you're after?

Comment: yes I want Foo to initialize any child classes that extend it.  I freely admit that I could be going about it wrong, but at its most basic i need be able to manipulate Foo from outside the Foo class anytime Foo is initialized.  i am actually the one trying to do the extending here, (trying to extend someone else's wordpress plugin class) so I'm trying to work out if there is a way to even do it.

Comment: OK, i think i'm with you. So, there's a bunch of calls to `Foo` going on (perhaps called by either you or other code that already exists), and instead of `Foo` running as it currently exists, you basically want your own implementation of `Foo` to run instead, like some `Bar` class which extends `Foo`? Are you free to edit `Foo` itself?

Comment: yes to the first part.  and no, i cannot freely edit Foo myself, but if I can make a suggestion that will make Foo easier to extend for myself and for others then it would probably be implemented as long as it didn't effect the current implementation of Foo

Comment: There is no "natural" way to tell a parent class that it has X child classes that have to be initialized, unless you make a list of some sort that holds the names of those classes. It is also not the way inheritance works. You don't tell parent to create children, you tell the child it borrows from parent. Sadly, the approach you're trying to use isn't what's going to make your app modular, you're doing it literally - the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think given the information you've provided, if you really can't edit the implementation of `Foo` in any way, then you're pretty much out of luck.

Inheritance won't work for you, since that would require `Bar` to be the instantiated class, not `Foo`. You can't silently usurp `Foo`s functionality with `Bar` when other code will be making new objects of type `Foo`.

Given that you mentioned it's Wordpress related, you could always ask the plugin developer to add hooks to their `init` process to allow you to extend the functionality. This is basically how Wordpress goes about allowing their code to be extended by third-party code.

Comment: understood.  still getting my head around OOP so i didn't know if there was something i didn't know.  so you think that if the original plugin adds a hook and passes the object created by the parent class, i'll be able to modify the object from my own files?

Comment: Well, they might not want to give you the whole object to play with. Usually you get "last word" control over manipulations on a set of data. E.g. they'll run their `setAttributes` method that operates on an array, and then run a `do_action` on a hook that you've registered so that you can then add/alter attributes before they finally get processed. It's worth noting that that's not really an OO practice - native WordPress doesn't really care much for Object-Orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as frameworks like Zend does this.

put all child classes in the folder let say plugin folder and name the file same as the class name. like for put `class Bar {}` in Bar.php in plugin folder

in Bar.php

```
class Bar extends Foo {
   function construct(){
    parent :: __construct;
  }
   $this->foo = "foo is now bar";
}
```

And Class Foo will be

```
class Foo {
__construct(){

foreach (glob("plugins/*.php") as $filename) // will get all .php files within plugin directory
  {
    include $filename;
    $temp = explode('/',$filename);
    $class_name = str_replace('.php',$temp[count($temp)-1]); // get the class name 
    $this->$class_name = new $class_name;   // initiating all plugins
  }


}
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->bar->foo;  //foo is now bar
```

Hope it helps , Regards

Comment: that's very clever.  thanks i definitely learned something from this, but since i'm the one trying to build the add-on/plugin, this is probably a bit much for me to demand of the parent class' author.